# How to invoke a service in a controller in Grails?

Tags: grails, oauth

I'm writing a REST client in Grails, I need to use OAUTH for integration with a third party CRM so I'm using HTTP-Builder. I'd like to abstract the OAUTH stuff to a service and make the token and instance_url available to controllers and views.

Here's my service:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

class APIConnectorService {

    def sf_login_domain = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
    def instance_domain
    def access_token = ''
    def consumer_key =    'STUFFTHATWORKS'
    def consumer_secret = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
    def auth_username = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
    def auth_password = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'

    def serviceMethod() {

        //Request Access_token and instance domain for work
            def http = new HTTPBuilder(sf_login_domain)
            def postBody = [
                grant_type: 'password',
                client_id: consumer_key,
                client_secret: consumer_secret,
                username: auth_username,
                password: auth_password+auth_security_token
                ]
        try{

            http.post( path : 'services/oauth2/token',
                      body : postBody,
                      requestContentType: URLENC) { resp, json ->
                            access_token = json.access_token
                            instance_domain = json.instance_url +"/"
                        }

        }catch(HttpResponseException e){
            println "Error code: ${e.statusCode}"
            println "Post form: $postBody"
        }

        println "Access Token $access_token"
        println "Instance domain $instance_domain \n"

  }
  }
```

And here's my Contoller

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON



class APIConnectorController {

def APIConnectorService

def index(){


    http = new HTTPBuilder(APIConnectorService.serviceMethod())
    http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
      uri.path = 'services/data/v28.0/'
      headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"


    response.success = { resp, json  ->
        assert resp.status == 200
        json.each{ key,value ->
        render(view:"index", model: [json: json])
            }
        }

    response.failure = { resp, json ->
        println resp.status
        println json.errorCode
        println json.message
      } 
    }
    }
 }
```

So when I include all the service code directly in the controller it behaves the way I'd like but, as I said I'd like to abstract the OAUTH token generation to a service (at least, this makes the most sense to me).

I get this error when I try the above configuration

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /SFAPITest/APIConnector
No signature of method: sfapitest.APIConnectorController.HTTPBuilder() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: sfapitest.APIConnectorController.HTTPBuilder() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
```

UPDATE!!

I'm getting the access token and instance domain passed from the service to the controller but now I' getting the error:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /SFAPITest/ApiConnector
No signature of method: sfapitest.ApiConnectorController.HTTPBuilder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://scholastica--FullBox.cs16.my.salesforce.com/]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: sfapitest.ApiConnectorController.HTTPBuilder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://ourschool--FullBox.cs16.my.forcefulCRM.com/]
```

Here is my updated service

```
package sfapitest

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

class ApiConnectorService {

def transactional = false

def sf_login_domain = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
def instance_domain
def access_token = ''
def consumer_key = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
def consumer_secret = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
def auth_username = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
def auth_password = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
def auth_security_token = 'STUFFTHATWORKS'
def api_token_path = 'services/oauth2/token'
def oauthObject

 def serviceMethod() {

    //Request Access_token and instance domain for work
        def http = new HTTPBuilder(sf_login_domain)
        def postBody = [
                grant_type: 'password',
                client_id: consumer_key,
                client_secret: consumer_secret,
                username: auth_username,
                password: auth_password+auth_security_token
                ]
        try{

            http.post( path : api_token_path,
                       body : postBody,
                       requestContentType: URLENC) { resp, json ->
                             access_token = json.access_token
                             instance_domain = json.instance_url +"/"
                        }

                    oauthObject = [access_token, instance_domain]

        }catch(HttpResponseException e){
            println "Error code: ${e.statusCode}"
            println "Post form: $postBody"
        }

    return oauthObject
}
}
```

So thanks to advice below, I'm returning an array of the access_token and instance _domain to the serviceMethod().

Here's my controller:

```
package sfapitest


import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON



class ApiConnectorController {

def apiConnectorService

def index(){

    def access_token = apiConnectorService.serviceMethod()[0]
    def instance_domain = apiConnectorService.serviceMethod()[1]


    http = HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
    http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
      uri.path = 'services/data/v28.0/'
      headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"


    response.success = { resp, json  ->
        assert resp.status == 200
        json.each{ key,value ->
        render(view:"index", model: [json: json])
            }
        }

    response.failure = { resp, json ->
        println resp.status
        println json.errorCode
        println json.message
      } 
    }
}
}
```

MissingMethodException might mean that I dont have the correct number of arguments. I can render the access_token and instance_domain from the cotroller and they show the correct values. Any hints and pointers about how to make this work and be more elegant would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to make a RESTful / OAUTH app that can be used for various thrid party webservice integrations.

Comment: @Lorenzo, I'm now returning the access_token and instance_domain to the controller from the service. Thanks! But I'm getting the error 'No signature of method: ApiConnectorController.HTTPBuilder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://ourschool--FullBox.cs16.my.forcefulCRM.com/]'

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `APIConnectorService.serviceMethod()` as parameter in

```
http = new HTTPBuilder(APIConnectorService.serviceMethod())
```

Your method `serviceMethod()` `returns` nothing so that's why I think you're getting this error.

`serviceMethod()` should return `Object defaultURI`

[HttpBuilder API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.html)

```
HTTPBuilder()
```

Creates a new instance with a null default URI.

```
HTTPBuilder(Object defaultURI)
```

Give a default URI to be used for all request methods that don't explicitly take a URI parameter.

```
HTTPBuilder(Object defaultURI, Object defaultContentType)
```

Give a default URI to be used for all request methods that don't explicitly take a URI parameter, and a default content-type to be used for request encoding and response parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after lots of trial, error and parsing the HTTPBuilder docs, the final piece was to properly define the new HTTPBuilder() instance in my controller.

```
    def http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
    http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
    uri.path = 'services/data/v28.0/'
    headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"
```

This now allows me to abstract the OAUTH component out of the controllers. I am absolutley sure there is a more elegant solution for what I'm trying to achieve. I'd love to hear some suggestions on how to clean this up.

- Do I need the imports in the service AND the controller?
- Can the OAUTH stuff be put in a config.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with the way you have declared your service try using

`def aPIConnectorService`

instead of

`def APIConnectorService`

Best would be to change the service name to be **ApiConnectorService** and declare in the controller like following

`def apiConnectorService`

Answer (score 0):

Your serviceMethod's last action is a println which causes to return null.
To access the http-builder object you have to return it after your successful post-request.

Comment: After omitting the printlns I'm getting _something_ through from the service, just not the object elementys I want. How might I cleanly _return_ the object?
 Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: sfapitest.ApiConnectorController.HTTPBuilder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [https://ourschool--FullBox.cs16.my.forcefulCRM.com/]'

Answer (score 0):

Might be caused by not following proper Naming Conventions.

First suggestion would be to change the service name by following class naming conventions.

```
ApiConnectorService
```

and then using camel case declaration for your service in the controller.

```
def apiConnectorService
```

A grails uses its conventions to find names and its classes.

Also try using

```
APIConnectorService apiConnectorService
```